# Vue, flow between Vuex and Vue component

Tags: vue.js, vue-component, vuex

Im devoloping a Vue Frontend and my problem is the flow between Vuex and vue component. 
 
Vuex component

```
const state = () => ({
User: {
    Firstname: '',
    Lastname: '',
    MainAccountBalance: '',
    SubAccount: []
}
})

 const getters = {
   getUserData(state) {
       console.log("3 Dashboard: getter")
       return state.User;
   }
};
 
const actions = {                               
    async fetchUserProfile({commit}, payload) {
        await instance.post(UserAccounts, {
               token: payload.token
            })
            
        .then(response => {
            console.log("1 Dashboard: fetchUserProfile");
            commit('saveAccounts', response.data);
            return JSON.stringify(response.data);
        })
    }
};
 
const mutations = {
    saveAccounts(state, data) {
        const newModel = {
            Firstname: data.Firstname,
            Lastname: data.Fastname,
            MainAccountBalance: data.MainAccountBalance,
            SubAccount: data.SubBankAccounts
        }
        console.log("2 Dashboard: Mutations")
        state.User = newModel;
    }
  
};
```

fetchUserProfile is getting called from Vue component and gets commited to saveAccounts where it will set data for state variables. All of this works fine, and in correct order. The problem starts with when i want to get the data from the State using getters.
Vue component

```
      computed: {
    ...mapGetters("auth", {
      getUserData: 'getAuthData'
    }),
  },
  methods: {
    ...mapActions("dashboard", {
        userProfileaction: "fetchUserProfile"
    }),

    getUserToken() {
      this.access_token = localStorage.getItem("access_token")
      return this.access_token;
    },
     async saveUserData() {
      var userToken = this.getUserToken();
      await this.fetchUserProfile({token: userToken})

      this.Firstname = this.getUserData.Firstname;
      this.Lastname = this.getUserData.Lastname;
      console.log("Last Show accounts: "+  this.getUserData.User.Firstname)
    }
  },
  mounted() {
    this.saveUserData()
    console.log("test")
  }
```

How would i use getters correct so it doesent execute before the variables are set on Vuex? Is there an better alternative way?

Comment: First of all you use async/await and then chaining together. Format it to async/await

Comment: You defined method userProfileaction but uses the name defined in the store

Comment: I have changed userProfileaction, a mistake i forgot to edit before uploading. Where do you want me for format it to async/await? As i understand, i have only set async / await on call to api and i dont think i need async and await to save response to State. And on the component i dont think i need async / await to call getters?

Comment: Look at your fetchUserProfile method

Comment: If you mean fetchUserProfile in Vuex actions, it works just fine and it commits fine to mutations where i can console.log(JSON.stringify(data)) and see the JSON data. The problem is after. it just seems the getters execute to early and i cant "const response = await this.fetchUserProfile({token: userToken})" on Vue component and see the data in that variabel.

Comment: Do what I said above and you should see the data in your variable

Comment: Could u give me an example? I dont know what you mean by look at fetchUserProfile, as i see it, it is already async and await.

Comment: Not at laptop at the moment. In your method where you’re trying to get data from you’re not returning anything. That’s why it’s empty. Read more about the ways of how to work with the promises

Comment: [enter link description here](http://Read%20it) and maybe read more about scopes and functions in your case

Comment: In short remove then in your action method and it should look like this const res = await instance.post() and so on where you return the result

Comment: Yes that works when I return it. Never thought that .then would cause that trouble, especially because I could commit the data fine to mutations, so by that i thought it worked. I Thank you, and I gonna take your offer up on the reading materiel.